# How to resize datepicker text programmatically

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using rey5137's datepicker dialog, how to resize datepicker text size programmatically little bit bigger because in nexus 7, datepicker size is very small...this is the code example

```
case R.id.dialog_bt_date_light:
                builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(){
                    @Override
                    public void onPositiveActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                        DatePickerDialog dialog = (DatePickerDialog)fragment.getDialog();
                        String date = dialog.getFormattedDate(SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance());
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Date is " + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        super.onPositiveActionClicked(fragment);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNegativeActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Cancelled" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        super.onNegativeActionClicked(fragment);
                    }
                };

                builder.positiveAction("OK")
                        .negativeAction("CANCEL");
                break;
```

any help?

Comment: Which textsize you mean?

Comment: please see this [image](http://i.imgur.com/3KQHiod.png)

Comment: have you changed anything in styles.xml ? can you update if you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <style name="CustomStyle_DatePicker" parent="Material.App.Dialog.DatePicker">
        <item name="dp_dayTextSize">15sp</item>
   </style>
```

And apply this style to your datepickerdialog

```
 builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(R.style.CustomStyle_DatePicker) {....
```