# Resizing datepicker titletext/Timetext

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, datepicker

I'm having some issues with customizing a datepickers text. 
Working in Visual Studio with Xamarin (not forms).

I have tried some things but couldn't specify just the timetext.
Such as this topic: [How to resize datepicker text programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978730/how-to-resize-datepicker-text-programmatically/49763516#49763516)
but it is not recognizing dp_dayTextSize or tp_textSize.

My goal is to make it look something like the Google Calender datepicker. See screenshot:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT37u.png]

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App.Android.Fragments
{
    public class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment,
                                      DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        // TAG can be any string of your choice.
        public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

        // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
        Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

        public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
        {
            DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
            frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;
            return frag;
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;

            // THEME possible: AlertDialog.ThemeDeviceDefaultLight
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity, Resource.Style.App_Picker, this, currently.Year, currently.Month - 1, currently.Day);
            return dialog;
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            // Note: monthOfYear is a value between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12!
            DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
            Log.Debug(TAG, selectedDate.ToLongDateString());
            _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

My style for Resource.Style.HPA_Picker is as follows.

```
<style name="App.Picker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

I knew this wasn't gonna work but this is the best I could.
This is done in style but it may also be done programmatically.

What is the solution?

Comment: I have made a demo, look [here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/CalendarTest/tree/master).

Comment: Hey thanks this worked for me! basically I just had to remove in style App.Main theme the android textsize, and remove the App.Picker Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes basically I just had to remove the style entirely and remove text size of the app.main. I just figured it out after seeing your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/CalendarTest/tree/master) for you, in the project, I am using `Android.App.AlertDialog.ThemeDeviceDefaultLight` to achieve the style, you can refer to it.